# Express $c$ and $d$ in terms of $m$ where $c$ and $d$ are zeroes of $f$ where $m > -2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, roots, quadratics

Let $$f(x) = x^2 - mx -(6m^2+25m+25)$$ where $m > - 2$

It can be shown that $f(x)$ has two zeroes.

Suppose we have $c,d \in \mathbb R$ s.t. $c < d$ and $f(c) = f(d) = 0$, express $c$ and $d$ in terms of $m$, again > -2.

---

**What I tried:**

$c,d$ are the zeroes of $f$ right?

If so then

$$cd = -(6m^2+25m+25)$$

and

$$c+d = m$$

I solved the following:

$$d = \frac{m + \sqrt{m^2 + 4(1)(6m^2-25m-25)}}{2(1)}$$

$$c = \frac{m - \sqrt{m^2 + 4(1)(6m^2-25m-25)}}{2(1)}$$

Is that right?

Comment: Careful, $c+d = m \neq -m$, haven't checked anything else.

Comment: Why not use the quadratic formula....?

Comment: I don't understand the title and the attempt.  "$c$ and $d$ are zeros of $f$ and $m$"?  Should that just say zeros of $f$?  In that case instead of $c_+$, $c_-$, $d_+$, and $d_-$, you should just have one $c$ and one $d$, each coming from the quadratic formula.

Comment: @tilper Oh thanks That's what I get for typing that while sleepy

Comment: @ZainPatel Thanks! That's what I get for not double checking Vieta's

Comment: @WillFisher Didn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a quadratic formula of the form
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
The well know quadratic formula
$$x=\frac {-b\pm\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Gives us our solutions for $x $. Applying  this we find
$$\begin{align}
x &=\frac {m\pm\sqrt{m^2+4 (6m^2+25m+25)}}{2} \\
&= \frac {m\pm\sqrt{25(m+2)^2}}{2} \\
&= \frac {m\pm5(m+2)}{2}
\end{align}$$
Because $m>-2$ the discriminant is positive so we have that $d $ is given by choosing the $+$ and $c $ by choosing the $-$.

Comment: I have no idea what I was thinking at the time. Thanks Will Fisher! ^-^

Comment: Huge simplifications on $c$ and $d$ appear if only one looks carefully at the discriminant.